# Why does Postfix place mail in a different mail location than I put in main.cf?

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I'm trying to figure out why mail is not going to /home/username/Maildir and instead going to /var/spool/mail/

My postfix main.cf has `home_mailbox = Maildir/` and dovecot 10-mail.conf has `mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir`.

I installed dovecot-core, dovecot-imapd, and dovecot-lmtpd. Is lmtpd what communicates between postfix and dovecot?

I saw this `virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp` command in a how-to for main.cf but wasn't sure if I needed it or not.

Update: Resolved.

I had mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"

Commented it out and now it works.

Comment: Don't update the question to put the solution. Put the **solution** in the answer box below.